# How to get a list of Objects instead of a list of Maps in gremlin-javascript

Tags: javascript, gremlin

Hi I am now using gremlin -javascript to do some queries in AWS neptune DB.
I have a query like

```
[errRelatedTicket, relatedTicket] = await to(g.V().hasId(a).in_('r').valueMap(true).toList());
```

then I get a list of map like:

```
[
 Map {
   id: 1
 },
 Map {
   id: 2
 },
]
```

But can I use gremlin query to get id and properties in key/value pairs directly instead?
what I expect is:

```
[
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
]
```

Comment: like convert map list into object list in javascript

Answer (score 6):

I don't know "gremlin-javascript", you can research more in the document. But I know there's a simple way to do the conversion in plain javascript, use `.map` and `Object.fromEntries`. Hope you'll find a better way.

```js
var listMap = [ 
  new Map([[ 'id', 1 ]]),
  new Map([[ 'id', 2 ]]),
];

var listObject = listMap.map(m => Object.fromEntries(m));

console.log(listObject);
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. Thanks a lot for the answer. I was struggling for couple days until I saw this simple trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to return objects rather than maps, you can set this configuration in your DriverRemoteConnection construct, like so: `const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(CLUSTER_URL, { mimeType: 'application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json' });`